# 終わる to mean closed shop

Tags: grammar, nuances, tense, aspect

Is it a natural or at least used way to say "closed" like in that example, using the verb 終わる ?

> - A : 今7時ですが、スーパーは終わりましたか。
> - B : いいえ、8時まで開いているはずですよ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's used, but 終わっていますか may be more natural since you are concerned with the current state rather than the past event. 閉店していますか is a stiffer way of asking the same thing (preferred in emails etc), but 終わっていますか is perfectly fine in speech.